# Editing HTML file using Java

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I am able to parse the HTML file and make the required changes, but I am not able to store it as an output html file, ie, the changes are visible in console but not in the html file.
My requirement is to take a html file as an input, edit it and then store the html file with the new changes. So far, all I am able to do is display the changes in the console.

```
package html_editer;
import java.util.*;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;
import java.io.*;

public class editer
{
static String htmlLocation = "C:\\Desktop\\hello\\";               
static String fileName = "x";
static StringBuilder buildTmpHTML = new StringBuilder();
static StringBuilder buildHTML = new StringBuilder();
static String name = "Ankit";
static String address = "India";
static String phoneNumber = "1234567890";

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    readHTML(htmlLocation, fileName);
    modifyHTML();

    System.out.println(buildHTML.toString());

    buildTmpHTML.setLength(0);
    buildHTML.setLength(0);

    System.exit(0);
}

    public static void readHTML(String directory, String fileName)
{
    try
    {
BufferedReaderbr=newBufferedReader
(newFileReader(directory+fileName+".html"));

        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            buildTmpHTML.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}


public static void modifyHTML()
{
    String htmld = buildTmpHTML.toString();
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmld);

    final List<TextNode> nodesToChange = new ArrayList<TextNode>();

    NodeTraversor nd  = new NodeTraversor(new NodeVisitor() 
    {
      @Override
      public void tail(Node node, int depth) 
      {
        if (node instanceof TextNode) 
        {
          TextNode textNode = (TextNode) node;
          nodesToChange.add(textNode);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void head(Node node, int depth) 
      {        
      }
    });

    nd.traverse(doc.body());

    for (TextNode textNode : nodesToChange) 
    {
      Node newNode = buildElementForText(textNode);
      textNode.replaceWith(newNode);
    }

    buildHTML.append(doc.html());
}

private static Node buildElementForText(TextNode textNode) 
  {
    String text = textNode.getWholeText();
    String[] words = text.trim().split(" ");
    Set<String> units = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String word : words) 
        units.add(word);

    String newText = text;
    for (String rpl : units) 
    {
        if(rpl.contains("Name"))
            newText = newText.replaceAll(rpl, "" + rpl + " " + name);
        if(rpl.contains("Address") || rpl.contains("Residence"))
            newText = newText.replaceAll(rpl, "" + rpl + " " + address);
        if(rpl.contains("Phone-Number") || rpl.contains("PhoneNumber"))
            newText = newText.replaceAll(rpl, ""+rpl+" "+phoneNumber);
    }
    return new DataNode(newText, textNode.baseUri());
  }}
```

Comment: "*but I am not able to store it as an output html file*" sorry, but which part of your code makes you think that this HTML should be stored in any file?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I am able to display the changes in console, how do I make the same changes in the file itself?
Even if it is not possible to change the original file, I can have a new html file as output as well. Changing the original file is not a must, but having an html file as output with the changes incorporated is a must requirement.

Comment: Sorry, but are you asking "how to write text to file in Java"? There are a lot of questions about it here available, or any tutorial should contain part about it. Do you face any specific problem when you are trying to use solutions described there?

Comment: Yes, all I could find was the same thing, displaying changes in consoles. Can you suggest some post which has what I am looking for?
Or excerpt of code which will do the trick?

Comment: It is easy to find it on Stack Overflow using google with `site:stackoverflow.com` as target: https://www.google.pl/search?q=how+to+write+text+to+file+in+java+site:stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Googling for "java modify text file" also gives few interesting articles.